# Can I use dot sign in web service method name?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have to create webservice with method that contains '.' sign in it`s name. Is there any way I can do that in c# webservice?

I have to create web service that other company will use and their require is to call a method with specified name, for example "some.function". I've tried using MessageName with WebMethod attribute like this:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName="some.function")]
public string MyFunction(){
  return "something";
}
```

but soap client still has to call MyFunction, not some.function (I tried writing client in php, ruby, c#).

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)?

Comment: You can not declare a method name containing a `.`. But a webservice containing dot? yes.

Comment: A webService is, at the end, sending and receiving xml-soap messages(or json or xml or pure text etc.). You can always hook somewhere, read the message and dispatch to an appropriate function. I used many times HttpListener for these type of requests.